# Sylius error when adding to cart

Tags: php, symfony, shopping-cart, cart, sylius

I'm building a shop using some bundles provided by Sylius. I have installed the ResourceBundle, ProductBundle, OrderBundle and CartBundle so far.

I am having trouble when calling the 'sylius_cart_item_add' path on the product page:

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Event\CartEvent::__construct() must be an instance of Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Model\CartInterface, instance of XXXX\OrderBundle\Entity\Order given, called in /XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/vendor/sylius/cart-bundle/Sylius/Bundle/CartBundle/Provider/CartProvider.php on line 103 and defined in /XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/vendor/sylius/cart-bundle/Sylius/Bundle/CartBundle/Event/CartEvent.php line 42

I have installed CartBundle following **[the documentation](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusCartBundle/installation.html)** (I haven't created a CartItem entity, as is optional according to the guide). This is my config file for Sylius bundles (XXXX stands for my company name):

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        dinamic.product:
            driver: doctrine/orm
            classes:
                model: XXXX\ProductBundle\Entity\Product
                interface: Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\Model\ProductInterface
                controller: Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController
                repository: Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository

sylius_product:
    driver: doctrine/orm
    classes:
        product:
            model: XXXX\ProductBundle\Entity\Product
            controller: Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\Controller\ProductController
            repository: XXXX\ProductBundle\Repository\ProductRepository
            form: Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\Form\Type\ProductType

sylius_order:
    driver: doctrine/orm
    classes:
        order:
            model: XXXX\OrderBundle\Entity\Order
        order_item:
            model: XXXX\OrderBundle\Entity\OrderItem

sylius_money:
    driver: doctrine/orm

sylius_cart:
    resolver: XXXX.cart_item_resolver
    classes: ~

stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            sluggable: true
            timestampable: true
```

I would gladly appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

EDIT: looking in Sylius' code, the problem seems to be in CartBundle/Provider/CartProvider/getCart() function (line 101):

```
$this->cart = $this->repository->createNew();
```

This returns a Order object instead of a CartInterface one, seems that the repository is not configured correctly, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could work around the problem by making my Order entity implement CartInterface, I also modified my OrderItem entity to implement CartItemInterface.

Finally, this is my config.yml file

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        dinamic.product:
            driver: doctrine/orm
            classes:
                model: XXXX\ProductBundle\Entity\Product
                interface: Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\Model\ProductInterface
                controller: Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController
                repository: Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
        dinamic.cart:
            driver: doctrine/orm
            classes:
                model: XXXX\OrderBundle\Entity\Cart
                interface: Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Model\CartInterface
                controller: Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Controller\ResourceController
                repository: Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository

sylius_product:
    driver: doctrine/orm
    classes:
        product:
            model: XXXX\ProductBundle\Entity\Product
            controller: Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\Controller\ProductController
            repository: XXXX\ProductBundle\Repository\ProductRepository
            form: Sylius\Bundle\ProductBundle\Form\Type\ProductType

sylius_order:
    driver: doctrine/orm
    classes:
        order:
            model: XXXX\OrderBundle\Entity\Order
        order_item:
            model: Dinamic\OrderBundle\Entity\OrderItem

sylius_money:
    driver: doctrine/orm

sylius_cart:
    resolver: dinamic.cart_item_resolver
    classes: ~
```

Also, this is my route entry with the call to the controller:

```
XXXX_cart_item_add:
    pattern: /agregar
    defaults: { _controller: sylius.controller.cart_item:addAction }
```

I still want to know why the ResourceBundle repository doesn't use Cart instead of Order

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing `use Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Model\CartInterface`.

Comment: The file is in place, with CartItemInterface

Comment: @Joel Please gist the content of a file where error occurs.

Comment: @umpirsky I don't know which file contains the error. I think it happens inside SyliusCartBundle, but I can't pinpoint the error sadly.

Comment: @Joel Oh, looks like just your `XXXX\OrderBundle\Entity\Order` must implement `Sylius\Bundle\CartBundle\Model\CartInterface`. So, ist me `XXXX\OrderBundle\Entity\Order` please.

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer, but I still don't know why the ResourceBundle repository doesn't use Cart instead of Order. Here is the gist https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7ed2097810420a03fb62

Comment: @Joel Did you override `sylius.model.order.class` parameter?

Comment: No, but the route 'sylius_cart_item_add' that I'm using and gave me the error is from SyliusCartBundle, it should use its model, right?

Comment: @Joel No, it should use your model.